# Ajax Cross Domain Calls

Tags: ajax, json, cross-domain

Can we make Ajax request to a different instance of server(different port) running on the same machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some trickery.  Try [JSONP.](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)

Answer (score 6):

Different port means different domain for the browser. So you will hit the cross-domain barrier.

Like Stuart said, you could try using JSONP.

If you are using jQuery, I'd recommend http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/ if you want it to be as painless as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use easyXSS (http://easyxss.net) and follow the example at http://xsslocal.kinsey.no/projects/easyxss/example/methods.html, then you could do this quite easily by having a document on the domain that the xhr-request are hitting doing the real requests.