# $.ajax() error in jquery-1.6.2 but not in jquery-1.4.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I used `$.ajax()` to consume a local .asmx webservice. Here's my code for the call:

```
    $("#btnGetOne").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'http://localhost:53003/TestWebService.asmx/GetServant',
            data: '{ "servant_id": "' + $("#txtServantID").val() + '" }',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var jsnData = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                $('#DisplayArea').html(jsnData.Servant_Name);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see the ajax call executes when I click btnGetOne.

As in my question header, this works in jquery-1.4.1, but when I used jquery-1.6.2 I get an `errorThrown` saying `No Transport`.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think it's the actual problem, but something doesn't look right in your `success` handler: You've told jQuery that the response will be JSON, and so it will deserialize it for you, but then you're deserializing `data.d`. Unless your response data really defines an object with a property called `d` whose value is a string which *contains* further JSON data (which would be a bit odd, why embed JSON inside a string inside a response that's already in JSON?), I don't think you want that `parseJSON` call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Call to WebService returns "No Transport" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HTML+JS page is probably not loaded from `localhost:53003`, while you are trying to, using Ajax, an URL that is on domain `localhost:53003`.

So, it looks like you are trying to make a cross-domain request, which is forbidden -- see [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Taking a look a the documentation of [**`jQuery.support`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), you might want to enable `jQuery.support.cors` *(quoting)* :

> `cors` is equal to `true` if a browser can create an `XMLHttpRequest`
>   object and if that `XMLHttpRequest` object has a `withCredentials`
>   property.  
>  
> To enable cross-domain requests in environments
>   that do not support `cors` yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests
>   (windows gadget, etc), set `$.support.cors = true;`.

And here are a couple of links that might help :

- [jQuery Call to WebService returns “No Transport” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)
- [Force jQuery 1.5 to always allow cross-site scripting](http://blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=03aff202-4198-4606-b9d6-686fd13697ee)
- [BB5 - Fix for jQuery.ajax "no transport" error](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1908)

Comment: Hmmm... So does that mean that 1.6.2 has security updates now? Btw, the proj of the webservice is on the same vs2010 project, but I think your comment still applies. XD

~ update ~
You're right, I enabled `support.cors` and it works now. I think I should redesign my proof of concept to not use a separate webservice that's on the same machine.

Comment: @Erick I've edited my answer with a bit more informations, and a few links that point to something interesting ;-)