# Calling a webservice from jQuery returns “No Transport” error

Tags: json, web-services, jquery

I have the following web service;

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I am pointing to the latest jquery library.

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
```

I have this jQuery method;

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Service/AFARService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            // this._baseURL + method,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: fnSuccess,
            error: fnError,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataFilter: function (data) {
                var response;

                if (typeof (JSON) !== "undefined" && typeof (JSON.parse) === "function")
                    response = JSON.parse(data);
                else
                    response = val("(" + data + ")");

                if (response.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                    return response.d;
                else
                    return response;
            }
        });
```

When I execute I get a "No transport" error returned. I added  `crossDomain: true` still no success.

Thanks in advance
BB

Comment: The response from your server, `"Hello World"`, is not valid JSON!

Comment: What happens if you view `../Service/AFARService.asmx/HelloWorld` in the browser?

Comment: a similar question asked here maybe it'll help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error/5241121#5241121

Comment: Useful? Error hauntingly similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error

Answer (score 2):

to enable cross domain calls, you can try

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

if this doesn't works you can go through(JSONP) :
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/04/JSONP-for-crosssite-Callbacks
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

you can follow any of these

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 url: "AFARService.asmx/HelloWorld",



[WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```