# Problems with HTTPS Ajax Request In IE (Not Crossdomain)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I'm stumped on an issue I'm having with an HTTPS Ajax call in IE only. IE seems to think I'm making a crossdomain request, but I'm not. The following code is called from the page `https://mydomain/customer_profile.php`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'https://mydomain/ajax/retrieve_transaction_details.php',
    data: /* my data is here */,
    success: function(response){
        // do something with the response
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

This request works just fine in every browser except IE. In IE, the error function returns "Error: Access is denied". Like I said, I'm completely stumped on this, so any insight or ideas would be great.

Comment: Try it without the `https://mydomain`. So, try with the URL as "/ajax/retrieve_transaction_details.php".

Comment: I have tried this. For whatever reason, if I don't specify an absolute path, other browsers then try to make the request over HTTP, thus breaking it in those too.

Comment: Perhaps add a check for browsers which will follow a path if they use IE for compatibility and if they use any other browser then forward it to the code u already have working.

Comment: Firstly, verify that you don't have it set up so that you loaded the page from `http://www.mydomain` and your AJAX references just `http://mydomain` or vice versa - this might be considered X-domain. Next, try `://mydomain/ajax/retrieve_transaction_details.php` without `http`/`s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using the **`<base>`** tag inside the ***head*** section of your HTML; right?

If it is pointing to **`http`** instead of **`https`**, that would break **IE**.

Comment: Wow, that would in fact be it. I completely forgot I had thrown that tag in my header template. Funny it only broke it in IE, but I guess that's IE for ya. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try setting crossDomain to true in your request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'https://mydomain/ajax/retrieve_transaction_details.php',
    data: /* my data is here */,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response){
        // do something with the response
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

this should allow you to make the request regardless of whether it is cross-domain or not.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error