# 'No Transport' Error w/ jQuery ajax call in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, cross-domain

I need to use foursquare API to search venues. Of course it is cross-domain.

It has no any problems in Firefox but in Internet Explorer (7, 8, 9 I've tested).

My javascript code looks like:

```
searchVenues: function(searchQuery) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search',
       data: {
            sw: bound_south_west,
            ne: bound_north_east,
            query: searchQuery.query,
            oauth_token: FSQ_OAUTH_TOKEN,
            limit: 25,
            intent: 'browse',
            v: 20120206
       },
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           displayResults(data, searchQuery.query);
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
           console.log(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);
       }
    });
}
```

In Firefox, it perfectly displays received data.
In Internet Explorer, it logs on console:

```
No Transport
Error
Error
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check out the answers for [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

I tested this on Windows Mobile 7.

After LOTS of time spent to understand, I finally found this:

[http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10660](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906055648/http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10660)

The Solution is simple, just set this:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

and Ajax cross domain requests will work!

Comment: this is not working for IE browser... Can Any one please help me work it on IE

Comment: In my case, I also had to add 'crossDomain: true' to the .ajax method call in order for this work.

Comment: Thanks. After applying this, I'm now getting statusText as `"Error: Access is denied.\r\n"` on IE9. Any guesses? Nothing captured in network.

Comment: I am getting 'Error: Access is denied' as well on IE8 and IE9

Comment: It's a bit discouraging that the accepted answer doesn't actually solve the problem on IE8 or IE9.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Works in IE10 but not in IE8 or IE9

Comment: I also got "Error: Access is denied", my mistake was that I pulled HTTPS content from a HTTP domain. Make sure your website and your ajax target use the same protocols (either HTTP OR HTTPS)

Comment: I believe this is set by default now. For me the solution was an XDR request transport - see this popular answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10232313/217866

Comment: I would also suggest to check headers of url being sent a request to. If possible by the way.

Comment: Works on IE 6 like a charm. Ashamed to post this in 2022.

Answer (score 13):

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: "",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "xml",
  data: soapMessage,
});
```

you need to make the cross domain value to true

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and the accepted one, that was posted quite some time before yours?

Comment: @javanna The addition of `crossDomain: true` to the options argument.

Comment: What is the cross domain and why does it need to be true?

Comment: You don't need `crossDomain: true` that's what `$.support.cors` does by default if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 6):

This problem has been bugging me for some time. As a workaround I use proxy scripts located on the same site. Such scripts simply execute server-to-server non-ajax HTTP request (think of curl and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest) and pass status and data back to the caller. It works, but obviously not very efficient because it has to perform two HTTP requests.

In my case, solution is a combination of all the things described above plus 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

```
$.support.cors = true; // this must precede $.ajax({}) configuration

$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true, // added in jQuery 1.5
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  ...
});
```

The web service that answers these calls also responds with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header.

Comment: ... and yet this one is the first answer to mention the CORS header. The accepted solution did not work for me.

Comment: I guess this should rather be in the web.config of the service.

Comment: Adding that header to the client request makes no sense; it's [a response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463975/237091

Or, simply put this code in your HTML right after including jquery.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.3/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I found the same problem occurring in Chrome (and possibly Android Browser) on Android, so perhaps leave off the conditional comment to allow all browsers to use this script.

(The project home page is here: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)

Comment: This worked for me. In addition to making sure that the Response Content-type is 'text/plain'

Comment: I added it in Grunt after jquery and now it works (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ajax-transport-xdomainrequest).

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the jquery version and replaced the CDN link and it worked! Just do it if `crossDomain:true` and `$.support.cors` = true not work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```