# $.ajax async:false doesn't work in IE and Firefox, works in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to measure download speed with ajax call. 
Here is the my code

```
var start = new Date();
$.ajax ({
    url: 'https://www.example.com/perftest/dummyFile1024',
    cache: false,  
    success : function() {
        var total = (new Date() - start)
        alert(total)    
    },
    error : function(jqxhr, status, ex) {}
})
```

It doesn't wait until whole file loaded. When I add `async: false,` it waits for loading whole file and I am able to measure bandwidth at chrome and safari however internet explorer and firefox still works the same as `async: true,` they don't wait until whole file loaded. Do you have any idea how I can manage it works for I.E. and firefox as well? Thanks.

Comment: Does the requested URL reside on a different domain? Maybe it's a cross-domain issue.

Comment: yes it is cross domain. However it is cross domain for all browsers. why does it work well for chrome and safari?

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this? I don't see how the `success` callback can ever be called before all the results are loaded.

Comment: sorry couldn't set the library at fiddle.

Comment: Are you saying the `success` callback is executed before the response was retrieved? I highly doubt that.

Comment: no, it goes to success directly after response comes from server. so I check just response time from server not the time to load the 1 mb file (as I said at IE and firefox, chrome and safari works perfect).

Comment: @user1874941: What else do you mean with "load" if not "getting response from server"? What type of file is it?

Comment: It is a dummyfile. But I tried with pdf as well, result hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 8/9 cross domain requests require jQuery to use a different transport method which uses a XDomainRequest instead of the default XmlHttpRequest.

I believe the question has been answered already here: [question]: [CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest in IE8/9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9)

For FireFox try setting the "dataType" of the content returned by the $.ajax request.