# jquery .get not working in ie9 against google api

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, google-api

I can't figure out why the following bit of code is working perfectly in FF but not in IE9.

What the script does is that on click of a button, it picks some values like street, postcode and town from a form, builds a string, submits it to google, and returns the lat and long of that address (and puts that into two fields in the form)

```
$("#google_coordinates").live("click", function(){

    var string = encodeURIComponent($('#sAddressStreet1').val())+",";
    if($('#sAddressStreet2').val() != ""){
        string += encodeURIComponent($('#sAddressStreet2').val())+",";
    }
    string += encodeURIComponent($('#sAddressPostalcode').val())+",";
    string += encodeURIComponent($('#sAddressTown').val())+",";
    string += encodeURIComponent($('#sAddressCountryCode option:selected').text());

/* test with an alert - string shows fine in both FF and IE */    
    alert(string);

    $.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+string+"&sensor=false", function(xml){
       $(xml).find('location').each(function() {
           lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
           lng = $(this).find('lng').text();

/* test with an alert - fine in FF not in IE */    
alert(lat + ',' + lng);

               $("#sAddressLatitude").val(lat);

           $("#sAddressLongitude").val(lng);
       });
    });

    return false;
});
```

The url this script is submitting in this case is: =1363342459585">http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Servicev%C3%A4gen%207,311%2033,Falkenberg,Sweden&sensor=false&=1363342459585

I've tried changing the cache to false, used $.ajax in stead of $.get tested by putting in some alerts, but i just can't seem to get inside the $.get function

I've tried changing the MIME type as is suggested here http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests, but that didn't help eather.

Any ideas anyone?

EDIT: 
Even tried with json result from google, to see if the problem lies in the XML, but that does not work either.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+string+"&sensor=false",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(json){
        alert("hiero");
        lat = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lng = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        $("#sAddressLatitude").val(lat);
        $("#sAddressLongitude").val(lng);
    }
});
```

Comment: i have set up a test page (for the original xml script) here: http://www.abitnerdy.se/test/ in firefox all works fine, ie chokes in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're performing a [cross-domain request](http://enable-cors.org/), the browser needs to support this. Most modern browsers (like FF and Chrome) support it, but IE9 only supports it when specific requirements are met.

[Here's what Microsoft has to say about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx), including some pointers on how to get it working (provided all the requirements as mentioned on the Microsoft page *can* be met).

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Knowing what to google for, i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9  what pointed me to a tool that helped to solve my problem. which can be downloaded here: https://github.com/Ovea/cors/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/ovea/cors/jquery.ie.cors.js

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting crossDomain to true in your $.ajax params?

Check the reference here for the crossDomain:bool param: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It should work seamlessly between browsers.

**Edit**

After checking jQuery's source, seems there's no mention of XDomainRequest (the way ie8/9 support CORS), so I'm not sure it works. Otherwise, if you really want to support those, make a wrapper around $.ajax with XDomainRequest if browser == ie9 or ie8.