# Ajax cross domain calls with IE7, 8 and 9

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I need to make calls using Ajax to PHP files that query a database . The PHPs are on a different domain to the HTML files, therefore my current code won't work in IE,7, 8 and 9. Here are examples of the calls to the phps on the other domain.

```
 $.post('http://other-domain.com/promo_subscribe.php', subscribeData, function(data){

    }

 $.get('http://other-domain.com/misc/promo_getstate.php', {
                crossDomain : true,
                cache:false,
                email: emailaddress,
                country: 'DE',
                lang: lang,
                source: 'Spring_dly'
            }, function (test) {


            }
```

What is the best option for me? Does it require  a back end change ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question specifically but you can do cross-domain calls with IE. They require use of the XDomainRequest object and have some special considerations. Here is more useful info:

[CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest in IE8/9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9)

Comment: does this support IE7 too?