# Get JSON via javascript cross-domain aspx webMethod

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain

Please help me to solve the following.

There is the client side code to get JSON data from my server:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: "{'em':'1'}",
      url: "http://myserver/default.aspx/GetInfo",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, field) {
          alert(field);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And there is the aspx page on my server with the code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetInfo(string em)
{
  return "{\"a\":\"" + em + "\"}";
}
```

The task is to create the web method on my aspx page placed on my server for the client to get JSON data to him. When I test it locally it works but when I call web method from the server it doesn't. I know that I should change client code to work with cross-domains but how i should do it when I have web method on server side?

Comment: The request is restricted by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which can only be relaxed when both the server [and browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (note: [jQuery doesn't support `XDomainRequest` on its own](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11487216)). And, official support for CORS within ASP.NET is primarily [only for Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), and that's a recent addition (VS 2013).

Comment: I thought that I should use jsonp instead but how I can apply it to webmethod.

Comment: Well, you can't `POST` with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). It can make cross-origin requests because it uses a `<script>` rather than an `XMLHttpRequest`. But, that limits it to `GET` requests.

Comment: So what is the way to solve the issue? Maybe I should not use webmethod and use page call instead?

Comment: And what about using JSONP with parameters and GET?