# IE 9 access denied on cors request using jQuery ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain, cors

I've read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied) and included the **jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js** after jQuery,
but I still get the 'Access Denied' error response. This request does work in browsers, but doesn't work in ie 9.
The server response headers include :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:166
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Javascript function executed:

```
function doStuff()
{
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://foo/bar',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                doSomething();
            });
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
    });
}
```

Comment: CORS is enabled on the server and works on other browsers?

Comment: Yes. It does work on chrome and firefox and ie 10+, thanks.
I thought Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* does meat the CORS is enabled on server.

Comment: @mishap Perhaps [CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest in IE8/9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9). The 4th and 7th restrictions discussed in the article seem most likely to apply here.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, removed it, same story.