# CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cors

Taking a look at [CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest in IE8/9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9?rq=1)

Is there way to support CORS with IE7?

(sadly we still need to support IE7 here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. XDomainRequest is only available for IE8 and IE9. For browsers such as IE7, you would need to adopt some alternate means of cross-origin data retrieval, such as JSON-P, Flash or proxying through a server.

Comment: XDomainRequest is available in IE10 as well.