# Custom ajaxTransport function without specified dataType is not firing (AT ALL!)

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I have been trying to setup [custom ajaxTransports for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Transports) to short-circuit some workflows in certain scenarios for our product.  However, I have had zero success in getting these transports to be honored (whereas I have many working [custom ajaxPrefilters](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Prefilters)).

**Tested with multiple versions of jQuery:**

- 1.5.2
- 1.6.4
- 1.7.2
- 1.8.0

**Tested with multiple browsers:**

- Firefox 15
- Chrome 21
- iOS 5 webviews

...

None of them worked.

**JsFiddle test case:** http://jsfiddle.net/PVYut/

...

If I add a `dataType` to narrow it down, then it works fine.

**JsFiddle test case:** http://jsfiddle.net/PVYut/1/

...

Am I just doing something all wrong?  I'd be happy to be told so, so long as I can get this working! -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajaxTransport("+*", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR, headers, completeCallback   ) {
    console.log("Executing ajaxTransport");
    return {
        send: function( headers, completeCallback ) {
            completeCallback(404, "error", {});
        },
        abort: function() {
          /* abort code */
        }
    }
});

$.ajax("?jqTrans=" + (+(new Date())))
    .done(function() {
        console.log("ERROR: Should not have been successful!");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("SUCCESS: Should have failed.");  
    });
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVYut/2/)

Comment: Nice, thanks! Another case of poor documentation for jQuery. =(

Comment: Usually, transports are used as fallbacks. You should never rely on transport ordering like this (hence why it is not documented). Create a prefilter, redirect to another dataType and capture this dataType with your custom transport is the way to go. Sorry to be late to the party.

Comment: @JulianAubourg I considered doing exactly what you described but the thought of obscuring the real `dataType` put me off. At best, you could store the real `dataType` value in a new property on the `options`/`settings` object for the request in the prefilter and then restore it to the `dataType` property in the transport. Doable but it makes it feel hackier.

Comment: In your prefilter: "return 'myDataType';" in you transport: "options.dataTypes.shift();" -> done! and you even kept the dataType chain. If you think of a mock ajax for instance, it makes a lot of sense: $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) { if ( options.mock ) { return "mock"; }); $.ajaxTransport( "mock", function( options ) { options.dataTypes.shift(); /* Now I have the actual dataType chain to do my mocking */ }); I think it's actually pretty elegant.

Comment: @JulianAubourg Once again, sounds like a result of poor documentation: the `dataTypes` property of the `options`/`settings` object does not appear to be mentioned anywhere either. I would agree that your modified suggestion is likely more preferable.

In my mind, I was picturing the need to do it more like this ugliness:
`$.ajaxPrefilter(function(o) { if (o.mock) { o.origDataType = o.dataType; o.dataType = "mock"; }});`
`$.ajaxTransport("mock", function(o) { o.dataType = o.origDataType; delete o.origDataType; /* pertinent real code */ });`

Comment: It's quite difficult to talk about internal options (like dataTypes) in the API site. I hope to find some time to properly document all of this separately.