# Web API with CORS

Tags: web-services, iis

I am developing a ASP.NET Web API and using CORS to allow for cross domain calls. When I run the service in Integrate Pipeline mode the calls to the web service work ok, but when I change it to Classic mode (which I need to run due to some calls the service makes), I get a 404 error whenever the browser makes the CORS pre-flight Options call. It doesn't appear that my service is ever getting a change to handle the options request. I am running the service on IIS 8.5. Anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Check that your handlers take care of the OPTIONS verb, not just PUT and POST. Also try removing the WEBDAV handler, it can sometimes hijack options requests.

Comment: Yeah, I did those following the steps in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495240/iis-hijacks-cors-preflight-options-request, but still no luck.