# "The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'" when using EnableCors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I want to enable CORS on one specific action in an Asp.net Web Api. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
[Route("api/mycontroller/myaction")]
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors("https://example.com", "*", "post")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction()
{
    ...
}
```

But when I send an OPTIONS request to the route, I get back an error: "The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'." I also tried removing the [HttpPost] annotation to no avail.
What am I missing?

Comment: hmmm, have you tried just sending the request as a POST and not OPTIONS? I think when you make a CORS request, the browser does the OPTIONS stuff for you in the background (I could be mistaken though).

Comment: The POST request itself works, but the browser first sends an OPTIONS request and that fails, so it never ends up sending the POST.

Comment: [EnableCors("https://example.com", "*", "post, options")]?

Tell the action to accept OPTIONS requests as well as POST

Comment: Same. If I add the [HttpOptions] annotation along with [HttpPost], I don't get an error but then it tries to execute the action method and wants authorization. EnableCors is supposed to respond to OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably missed the higher level call to `HttpConfiguration.EnableCors`, as described here: https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html.

> Add this code to your configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

Comment: I thought that calling `config.EnableCors()` in WebApiConfig.cs would enable CORS for the whole API. I didn't realize that it is a prerequisite for using the annotations. I also did have OWIN CORS installed, which I removed as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452419/560722

Answer (score 7):

For me, I added the following headers to the request by adding the following code to the **Application_BeginRequest** function of the **Global.asax.cs** file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type", "accept", "pragma", "cache-control", "authorization");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I have little idea why this works. 
Out of curiosity, I tried adding all headers by using an asterisk but then Web API complained that the Authorization header was missing.

Comment: you saved my life :) also i need to add the code to web.config file inside the system.weserver tag `<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>`

Answer (score 5):

To ensure the `OPTIONS` request gets handled by your application code and not some other part of the system before it reaches your app code, you may try adding the following to your `web.config`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

You might also need to include:

```
<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS"
  modules="IsapiModule" requireAccess="None"
  scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll"
  resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

See the answer at [IIS hijacks CORS Preflight OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495240/iis-hijacks-cors-preflight-options-request/40412986#40412986).

Or maybe even just this:

```
 <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS"
   modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
```

If none of that on its own works, then in your `global.asax` or other code you might try:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
}
```

…or some other variation on that, for example:

```
if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.OridinalIgnoreCase)
    && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Regardless of what specific code you use to do it, the point is to:

- make sure `OPTIONS` requests are actually getting caught/handled by your application code—not caught/handled by some other part of the system before ever reaching your app code
- make sure you have explicit handling for `OPTIONS` requests in your application code
- make the `OPTIONS` handling in your application code just do `Response.Flush()`

Or another approach I’m not sure is relevant to your situation as coded but I’ll mention just in case:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer, I have to maintain an old site and `<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS"
   modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />` works.