# Handle pre-flight OPTIONS request send before CORS in IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

We are currently working with a team on two different RestAPIs. One is our main system and the other one is just an empty host with IdentityServer registered in it. We have successfully configured `CORS` and pre-flight `OPTIONS` handling in the main app, but now we are struggling with `OPTIONS` in IdentityServer (`CORS` is enabled and working). Unfortunately, we have some specific headers that are needed in token request and browser is sending pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. Every time we do that, we get:

```
The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'OPTIONS'.
```

In our RestAPI application pipeline we just had to create `DelegatingHandler`:

```
public class OptionsHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
        {
            var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();

            var controllerRequested = request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;
            var supportedMethods = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions
                .Where(d =>
                    {
                        var controller = d.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                        return string.Equals(
                            controller, controllerRequested, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    })
                .Select(d => d.HttpMethod.Method)
                .Distinct();

            if (!supportedMethods.Any())
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                return response;
            });
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And register it in `Global.asax`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new OptionsHttpMessageHandler());
```

I have no idea how to register it in IdentityServer pipeline. Here's the simplified implementation of Owin Startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.IdentityServer.Host.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace.IdentityServer.Host
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var identityServerServiceFactory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
                .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get());

            identityServerServiceFactory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => UserServiceFactory.Create());

            app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
            {
                idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "MyNamespace.IdentityServer",
                    SigningCertificate = this.LoadCertificate(),
                    Factory = identityServerServiceFactory
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Tried so far:**

1. Setting some ISS handlers in `<handlers>` section in web.config

   - [How to support HTTP OPTIONS verb in ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095777/how-to-support-http-options-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-webapi-application)
   - [IIS hijacks CORS Preflight OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495240/iis-hijacks-cors-preflight-options-request)
   - and many more, all about this approach
2. I don't remember where I found this solution, but someone suggested to do the following:

   - register host API before IdentityServer
   - create a controller with routing set to address we want to hijack OPTIONS requests (in my case `/identity/connect/token`)
   - add `[HttpOptions]` tagged action, which returns `200, OK`

   … but unfortunately, as I expected, my new controller hijacked all the traffic to the IdentityServer, not only `OPTIONS` requests.

**Update - forgot to mention about third option**

3. I've come up with a solution that works (I mean almost because I haven't finished yet). It's simple, but **I would rather avoid such an approach**, because it adds additional work and, later on, code to maintain. The idea is to simply wrap `IdentityServer's` token endpoint in our own endpoint, so that AJAX calls only our RestAPI. And, as I stated before, our host is already set up for `CORS` and pre-flight `OPTIONS`

Comment: Unrelated side note: use `Task.FromResult` (or mark method with async) instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` in your `OptionsHttpMessageHandler`, `StartNew` is completely unnecesary here (and wastes time and resources, even if a little bit).

Comment: To be honest, it was just copy-pasteD from an external website, we just verified it works. But thanks for the advice, I will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to overcome this issue. **I hope this is only temporary solution** because it's neither elegant nor secure (I think it might open a way for some kind of attacks, but I am the beginner in security).

**I am still waiting for better solution, and I'm willing to change accepted answer.**

The solution was proposed by `Chtiwi Malek` in the other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33408512/2342898), which I also provided in my question (my fault, I didn't check all of the answers).

All we have to do is to handle `OPTIONS` at the beginning of every request

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
    res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");

    if (req.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        res.StatusCode = 200;
        res.End();
    }
}
```

(I've copied `AppendHeader`s here from `Chtiwi Malek's` answer, but these is handled in my `web.config`)

We also have to enable `OPTIONS` requests for our application in `web.config`

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```