# React-call to "Asp.Net Core with identity server" gives CORS-errors

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Ill try to keep this short to save digital rain forest. Please ask If I missed any details.

I have an "**asp .net 3.1 core + react**"-project template in VS, with built in Identity server. This works ok, but I now want to do my react project in a separate project. So I started a new create-react-app-project.

So, from my new react project, when I call OidcConfigurationController. The controller method is called and I can step through the code on server side. Then I get a client error "Failed to fetch", which, by internet wizdom, seems to indicated CORS-error.

This is what I got when I inspect the header in chrome dev toolbar->network

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5001/authentication/_configuration/MyProject.Web
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
:authority: localhost:5001
:method: GET
:path: /authentication/_configuration/MyProject.Web
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```

These are relevant lines in startup.cs

**ConfigureServices()**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                        builder =>
                        {
                            //builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3002/", "https://localhost:3001")
                            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                        });
});

services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>((container) => {
    var logger = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
    return new DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
    {
        AllowAll = true
    };
});
```

**Configure()**

```
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); // I also tried to switch order on these 2 rows
app.UseIdentityServer();
```

Nothing I do here seems to change the Referrer Policy in the header, still get the exact same message

The React-call is just a plain fetch(address-of-the-controller-that-it-hits).

I have also tried to start a new Server Side-project (asp net core api) and set same CORS-policy, I can call this api from my react client without getting any errors)

Comment: Can you show us your error message in dev tools? From your description, I can not find any errors.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the request, you see the origin: http://localhost:3000 header is used. That is the source for the CORS request. But the request is for this URL:

https://localhost:5001/authentication/_configuration/MyProject.Web

Could it not be that there's a redirect from insecure HTTP to HTTPS that is interfering?

Do make sure you set the CORS settings in IdentityServer as well.

See the [CORS](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html?highlight=cors) documentation for more details.

As side note, IIS might cause CORS issues as well, see this answer for details:

[IIS hijacks CORS Preflight OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495240/iis-hijacks-cors-preflight-options-request)

Comment: Hi Tore! Thanks for your reply! I will check this and reply after "normal" work

Comment: I would also post a copy of the failing request from Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler ) , its easier to pinpoint whats wrong there.