# Googlemaps Api v3 getJson not working in IE

Tags: api, internet-explorer, jquery

I have the following problem: I am trying to get data from the googlemaps api v3 via ajax with the code below. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE. What am I doing wrong?

```
var lat;
$.ajax({
url: "url",
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {      
lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
}                                                                                                   
});
```

Comment: Please add the error message you get from IE aswell as what version this is happening in.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following error event to your Ajax call

```
  success: function(data) {
     lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
     alert(status);
   }
```

And let us know what error message you get in IE, if any at all.

*EDIT* - Sounds like you are trying to do a cross-domain request?
If that is the case, try setting `$.support.cors = true;` before your ajax request.

Fetched from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

> To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but
>   do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set
>   `$.support.cors = true;`

*EDIT2* - Ill assume you are running IE9, in that case you need a plugin for jQuery found here: 
https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js

Also see this answer on SO for more details on why a plugin is needed for IE9 (with cors): [IE9 jQuery AJAX with CORS returns "Access is denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied)

*EDIT3* - Download [jQuery.XDomainRequest.js](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/blob/8754607e5f9ab73ccc37246f0c12fed14f85bd28/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js) and include it before your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error I'm getting is "No Transport".

Comment: I added $.support.cors = true; Now I get a new error: "Access denied". I really don't understand this, it still works well with both Chrome and FF.

Comment: Did you read the links i posted above? You need the posted plugin to make it work in IE9.

Comment: Just saw it. Looks very complicated, it seems this goes well beyond my understanding. Can you tell me how to use the plugin? where do I put this code? Thanks a lot!