# What is the impact of having $.support.cors = true; on Non-Cross browser ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

All,

I have a need to make cross-domain AJAX requests and hence added "$.support.cors = true;" line before my ajax requests.

But for non cross-domain calls, my ajax doesn't seem to hit.

Does this "$.support.cors = true;" has impact on the non cross-browser calls or am i seeing something wrong?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You'll get a better response if you define "doesn't seem to hit". Do you get errors? Does the response actually get loaded (check the network tab in your console)? What's the actual problem you're encountering?

Comment: setting $.support.cors to true doesn't do anything other than trick jQuery into thinking that all browsers fully support CORS, which is not true. IE < 10 does not support CORS in the same way that the other browsers do, therefore CORS will not work in IE< 10 in jQuery unless you extend jQuery.

Comment: The only time you should use `$.support.cors = true` is if you're using an environment where cors is supported but jQuery incorrectly detects that it isn't, such as phonegap.

Comment: @nrabinowitz, "doesn't seem to hit" means, that the request doesn't happen to the server. But the error might have been missed as I was not caching it till i read your comment.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, jQuery should detect CORS requests appropriately by default. Sounds like you should not set `$.support.cors`. The problem you are probably running into, without setting that, may be one of the following:

- The server you're hitting needs to allow CORS: it needs to put a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the specified `Origin` in the request header, or `*`, when returning the data; otherwise your browser will reject it.
- [IE8/9 doesn't allow CORS by default using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied), so you need to use this plugin:

  https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Comment: Just commented this elsewhere, but it should be noted that the MoonScript does not support cross protocol calls.