# Jquery ajax not working in IE9 even with cors = true

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer-9

This is my simple ajax code which works in FFX and Chrome but not in IE9. I am so much fed up of this browser I can't express. This is my jquery code:

```
   $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                crossDomain: true,
                cache:false,
                url: "http://somedomain.net/folder/ap/connector.php"
            }).success(function (result, payPalresult) {
});
```

inside document.ready and connector.php has

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

when I checked in Fiddler. Now this code works on FFX and Chrome but no ajax call is ever made in IE9

I even have this:

```
 $.support.cors = true;
```

Is there anything I am missing at this point? I am making an AJAX request from localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE9 jQuery AJAX with CORS returns "Access is denied"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't support IE's `XDomainRequest` object, which is what IE9 uses for CORS. Only IE10 does CORS with `XMLHttpRequest`. I believe there's a patch/plug-in you can find for jQuery that enables the `XDomainRequest` object. More information (including a link to a patch/plugin updated just six months ago, so fairly recent) in [this ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) on the jQuery website.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help the workaround for IE9 without using xdr (in the trusted sites zone at any rate) and presuming CORS is true and crossDomain is true.

When doing a POST, do **NOT** serialize the form but instead extract all the data you need out of the form and set each as name:value pairs within the $ data container. Then it works.

HTH