# Ajax Returns errorError: Access is denied on IE

Tags: jquery

My following code works great on Firefox and Chrome, but shows error-error: Access is denied on IE, can anyone help me with it please.

On Firefox it returns Success as status and same success status on Chrome not sure why it doesnt work on IE 9.0

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$.support.cors = true;
    $('#time').html(new Date());
    $('#status').html('');
    $('#content').html('');

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: $('#xhr_url').val()
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#status').html(textStatus+jqXHR);
        $.each(data.T2Json.PrinterManufacturers.Items, function (i, item) {
            $("#content").append('<a class="manufacturer" id="' + item.Id + '" onclick="hello(' + item.Id + ');" href="#">' + item.Name + '</a></br>');
        });
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        $('#status').html(textStatus + errorThrown );
        $('#content').html('(failed)' + errorThrown);
    });
});</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id='xhr_url' style='width:600px;' type='text' value='http://t2json.tgoservices.com/818746/PrinterManufacturers' />
<div id='content1'>ASS</div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Time:</legend>
    <div id='time'></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Status:</legend>
    <div id='status'></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Content:</legend>
    <div id='content'></div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you try to execute cross-domain request.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
What address has your page from which you try to execute ajax request and what is the value of `$('#xhr_url').val()`? Are they have same protocol, domain and port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied) out.

IE9 has known issues and limitations, as documented [here](http://enable-cors.org/client.html).

`Note: Supported somewhat in IE8 and IE9 using the XDomainRequest object (but has limitations)`

You can read about XDomainRequest limitations [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).