# How to make requests to a HTTPS API from a HTTP source in IE?

Tags: backbone.js

I am having issues with making HTTP requests to my API that uses HTTPS (I can't change this). My site, where the requests are made, uses HTTP so IE9< throws an "Access is Denied" error. Is there a way to customize Backbone.js so that this can work? BTW, everything works fine in Chrome, FF, IE10.

Comment: This is a jQuery/XHR issue in IE versions < 10. More details on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10232313/1048479)

Comment: That pages points to -> https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest which states "Protocol must be the same scheme as the calling page" :(