# IE8 ajax json call to google maps geocode never succeeds

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8, google-geocoder

I've just put up a jsbin at http://jsbin.com/ufiK/1/edit which illustrates the problem I'm having.  In Chrome or Firefox, when you load this page you'll get two alerts with some data coming back from the ajax call.  In IE8 the alerts never fire.  Can anyone tell me why this is?

This is the json non IE8 browsers return, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=san%20francisco%2C%20california

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, add `jQuery.support.cors = true;` before the ajax call. You have now solved the "No transport" error you had, but created a new "Access denied" error. For a solution to that error, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied).

Comment: Where are you seeing the no transport error?