# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, cors

I want to access information from same domain but with different port number, To allow this I am adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the response header.

**Servlet Code:**(present on www.example.com:PORT_NUMBER)

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");//cross domain request/CORS
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

**jQuery code:**(present on www.example.com)

```
$.post('http://www.example.com:PORT_NUMBER/MYSERVLET',{MyParam: 'value'}).done(function(data)
{
    alert(data);
});
```

Several times I am getting this error(in console):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://www.example.com:PORT_NUMBER/MYSERVLET'
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This error mostly occures first time when `$.post` gets executed. Second time it allows.

My question is that is there missing in `servlet` or in `jQuery` code?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update1**

I have changed:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

To:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
```

Then I am getting this error in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com:PORT_NUMBER/MyServletName
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' whitelists only 'http://www.example.com'
Origin 'http://www.example.com' is not in the list,
and is therefore not allowed access.
```

[Note: whitelist and origin are same, but still it gives error. It works sometimes, and gives above error sometimes.]

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: It's pretty simple: your server response does not include the proper CORS headers.  This is not a browser bug, and there is no client-side code issue.  If you want to get to the bottom of this, trace your server-side code a bit closer to ensure the headers are ALWAYS included in the response.  You should start by inserting a proxy between client and server to examine the headers yourself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Solution**:
Instead of using `setHeader` method I have used `addHeader`.

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

`*` in above line will allow access to all domains, For allowing access to specific domain only:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
```

For issues related to IE<=9, Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied).

Comment: what to do if we want to allow multiple domains? the second parameter would be like this? "http://www.example1.com","http://www.example2.com" or something else?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Have you tried writing addHeader twice? I think `addheader` method adds header and doesn't overwrite the existing ones.

Comment: What if I want to add two domains? I'm not sure if I'm thinking this right, but if I need to allow cors to two specific domains like www.example1.com and www.example2.com. The header should look something like response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example1.com, http://www.example2.com"); ? Or how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing 'json' dataType in the `$.post()` method:

```
$.post('http://www.example.com:PORT_NUMBER/MYSERVLET',{MyParam: 'value'})
        .done(function(data){
                  alert(data);
         }, "json");
         //-^^^^^^-------here
```

---

Updates:

try with this:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
```

---

Comment: Parsing the response is not the issue here.  The problem is that the response does not include the proper CORS headers.  This suggests a server side issue.

Comment: @RayNicholus _My question is that is there missing in servlet or in jQuery code?_ so i suggested the missing dataType from the `$.post()` method, because response is json from the server.

Comment: Again, the issue is a lack of a header in the response.  The content of the response is irrelevant here.  The code in the question isn't even making an attempt to parse the response.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution in [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/),like this:

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

Answer (score 0):

On your servlet simply override the service method of your servlet so that you can add headers for all your http methods (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, etc...).

```
@Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(("http://www.example.com").equals(req.getHeader("origin"))){
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.getHeader("origin"));
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
        }

        super.service(req, res);
    }
```