# Instagram Follower Count - Using jQuery / json & PHP

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, instagram

After a couple hours work and a little help from **Sahil Mittal** we've managed to retrieve the Instagram Follower Count using jQuery / json and PHP. This is what we've managed to put together and hope this helps anyone else looking to get Instagram information.

Our jQuery:

```
// INSTAGRAM COUNT WITH HOVER
    $('.instagram a').hover(
        function () {
            var instaurl = 'getdata.php'; // Add your PHP URL here.
            $.getJSON(instaurl, function(data){
                var instacount = data["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"];
                $('.instagram a').html(instacount);
            });
        },
        function () {
            $('.instagram a').html('Instagram');
    });
```

Our PHP (getdata.php) :

```
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header('Content-Type: application/json');    
   $instaurl = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXXXXX/?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); // Add your ID & Access Token
   echo $instaurl;
```

Comment: Follow this answer work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414606/getting-basic-information-from-instagram-using-php/31812442#31812442

Comment: This api isn't support anymore, do you have a new suggestion for getting the followercount?

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the strange brackets

```
var insta_count = data.data.counts.followed_by;
$('li.instagram a').html(insta_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong- `data["data.counts.followed_by"]`

Try this instead - `data["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"];`

**Edit**

You cannot fetch the data from api.instagram.com from ajax call due to No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881532/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) for details on this.

**Workaround**

Make a server call instead. Make a php file, say getdata.php

*getdata.php*

```
<?php
 $a = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/481503861/?access_token=53042481.ab103e5.0c6f8f50471a4e1f97595f8db529a47a");
 echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

*your ajax call*

```
 var instaurl = 'getdata.php';
 $.getJSON(instaurl, function(data){
     var instacount = data.data.counts.followed_by;
     $('.instagram a').html(instacount);
 });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sahil Mittal, Thank you for your ressponse unfortently I can't seem to get this working. I've updated my code above. Could you double check that everything looks good.

Comment: `console.log(data)` and tell me whats the output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50761/discussion-between-adam-wadsworth-and-sahil-mittal)

Comment: Add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to the php file and then check .