# Getting count of followers Instagram

Tags: api, social-networking, instagram

I want to get the count of recent unfollowers from my Instagram account. I have been googling around the internet but could not find the solution. I want to write the PHP script using Instragram API to perform this task. How can I achieve this. Please help me out.

Comment: it's not in the api but look at this stack overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090178/instagram-follower-count-using-jquery-json-php

Comment: Follow this answer work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414606/getting-basic-information-from-instagram-using-php/31812442#31812442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that data from API... the only way to do that is:

1 - Get all followers from API and store in your local database
some days before
2 - Get all followers from API again and:
2.1 - Compare with your local database
2.2 - See what users starts to follow (not in local database yet)
2.3 - See waht users unfollow you (in local database but not retrieved via API)

It's not glamorous, but will work fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use API.
https://github.com/criexe/api/wiki/Social-Networks-Page-Stats-API

GET `https://api.criexe.com/social/pageStats?instagram=microsoft`

```
{
   "instagram":{
      "user":"microsoft",
      "followers":1423870
   },
   "total":1423870
}
```

Comment: The repo isn't there anymore, do you have new links?