# Ajax, failed to load PHP from server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to make a PHP connection, but I keep getting this error. I am hoping someone can help.

My code gives the following error:

```
{
    "readyState": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost/php/busca.php'."
}
```

My code is:

```
SendSQL.onclick = function() {

    var dataString='a=hello&b=world';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://localhost/php/busca.php",
        data: dataString,
        async: false,
        dataType:'html',

        success: function(data){
                alert(data);
        },

        error: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //Better diagnostics
        }
    });

};
```

And the file busca.php is:

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    echo "$a, $b";
?>
```

Comment: what is SendSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878613/networkerror-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: on javascritp it is var SendSQL = document.getElementById('SendSQL'); but is a button on the html: <button id="SendSQL">SendSQL</button>

Comment: are you sure **http://localhost/php/busca.php** is the correct path? Do you see any error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach...

```
SendSQL.onclick = function() {

  var dataString='a=hello&b=world';

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"http://localhost/php/busca.php",
    data: {
      "a":"hello",
      "b":"world"
    },
    async: false,
    dataType:'text',
    success: function(data){
            alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: Thanks man, now i can see the error, it was missing a header header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Answer (score 0):

Your dataString is the way for sending parameter of GET request.

Let's change to JSON like

```
var dataString = { "a":"hello", "b":"world" };
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://localhost/php/busca.php",
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(dataString)},
        async: false,
        dataType:'json',

        success: function(data){
                alert(data);
        },

        error: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //Better diagnostics
        }
    });
```

And in php code, use `json_decode($_POST['data'])`

Comment: Already solved it, the problem was that a header were missing header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');