# jQuery Ajax call does not work if the Document Mode set to 9 or lower for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery Ajax call does not work if the Document Mode for Internet Explorer is set as 9 or lower. jQuery ajax call works if the Document Mode set to 10 or Edge.

Is there any workaround for the jQuery ajax call to work for Internet Explorer Document Mode set as 9.

Comment: some details would be super. like, is it a cross origin Ajax request?

Comment: yes it's a CORS request. But that works fine when document mode is 10 or Edge. But does not work when Document Mode is 9 or lower

Comment: @user dont forgot that latest versions of jQuery do not maintain old IEs. What version do you use?

Comment: Using Jquery 1.6.4, also tried with different new version of Jquery but no luck

Comment: I've read that jQueery AJAX with CORS is broken and wont be fixed in IE9 or less - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied - there's a plugin in the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX for the link. That link is really useful. By going through that link am able to make an ajax request in IE9. But one limitation is there only same protocol is allowed. I mean you can not make a https ajax call from the webpage launched in http mode.