# Autocomplete jquery work in firefox not in explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In this script http://jsfiddle.net/c4dSX/6/ autocomplete city whorks well in firefox not in explorer...why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is with trying to do a cross domain call from IE and it can't locate a transport. Make use of the error property in the [Ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

Reading a couple posts it seems that JSONP is your best bet. I have been trying to get it working in your example but maybe the service does not offer JSONP but I have not investigated the service much.

Have a look at these posts about the issue
[jQuery Call to WebService returns “No Transport” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)
['No Transport' Error w/ jQuery ajax call in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160123/no-transport-error-w-jquery-ajax-call-in-ie)

Comment: the service offer only JSON and xml

Comment: Have you tried looking at the solution in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11517652/560237
I have not had much experience with cross domain errors.
I guess another alternative is creating an end point in your application which your application calls to and that makes the call.

Comment: yes the problem is json crossdomain block i ask for jsonp at service