# Jquery Mobile Ajax error from a successful web api call (returns 200)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I get an ajax error that doesnt contain any details in 'errorThrown', but watching fiddler I can see the API call to the server and the 200 response with a Json object. Beside the Ajax error, everything is running perfect.  The server gets the proper data and returns 200.

Here is the server side code

```
    public JObject Post(JObject jobj)
    {
        var rtn = JsonServer.StaticJsonSrv.Post(jobj);
        //force return type to Json.. trying to fix JQM problem...
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        obj.Add("success", "true" );
        return obj;
    }
```

Here is the clients side code

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: URL,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
       success: function()
        {  
           alert("Status: success"); 
        },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            //alert("Status: " + textStatus); 
            alert("Errors: " + errorThrown); 
        }  

    });
```

Here is the result from the server

```
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Content-Length: 18
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
        Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 14:13:41 GMT

        {"success":"true"}
```

Comment: What is the ajax error?

Comment: Why don't you use dataType: 'json'?

Comment: @Gajotres, It was 'json', but switched it out based on a stackoverflow post trying to solve the problem.  I changed it back to json like it was before.

Comment: @galunano1 the error from the alert returned is "Errors: ".  I dont see an error in errorThrown in the chrome debugger also.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it in IE and I got a no transport error.  searching that gave me a solution from ['No Transport' Error w/ jQuery ajax call in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160123/no-transport-error-w-jquery-ajax-call-in-ie)

```
 $.support.cors = true;
```

Comment: I end up using a proxy server, cross domain is an issue that I dont seem to be able to resolve easily.