# JS Error TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I get this error in firefox, version 21, and this is a image gallery, images are from google+ api, in Firefox I get this error message:

> TypeError: currentthumb[0] is undefined

And in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: *Cannot set property 'src' of undefined*

On this line I have this code

```
currentthumb[0].src = seed2 + "s150-c/";
```

I can't fix this error, is this a array by variable or something others? Can this problem be the reason that I can't see images in the gallery on ie?

Comment: It basically means that your `currentthumb` array is null.

Comment: We need more code to help you out here..

Comment: I have uploaded my file here: [link]http://www.filedropper.com/file_155[/link], it is ok?

Comment: Please include the *relevant* part of the code in your question. I don't want to have to download a file.

Comment: Probably your images aren't found by the jQuery selector.. Did you write this plugin yourself? Try changing the line to this: `currentthumb.attr('src', seed2 + "s150-c/");`

Comment: are you using `currentthumb` before this line anywhere

Comment: To help yourself, have a look at [this article about debugging JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 2):

Harsha is correct,mostly. It means there is a Null pointer at currentthumb[0]  .
That does not mean the whole array is undefined.

It would be helpful if you posted sample code. (what do you think currentthumb[0] should be?)

something like this

```
 var currentthumb = []
 currentthumb[0] = new Image
 currentthumb[0].scr = "pathToImage"
```

you should also set the width and height

```
 currentthumb[0].height = 100
 currentthumb[0].width = 100
```

I don't know how fancy you want to get, but you must use the delete key word to delate objects before setting currentthumb[0] to a different object

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `jQuery(".thumb" + thumbindex + " > img");`, which is used to define `currentthumb` didn't find any elements. Therefor your `currentthumb` is empty and `currentthumb[0]` is undefined.

You want to check if any images were found by the selector, or set `src` the jQuery way:

```
 currentthumb.attr('src', seed2 + "s150-c/");
```

**EDIT**:

There was a load error in the plugin.

It was a "No Transport" error, which got me to this item on stackoverflow:

['No Transport' Error w/ jQuery ajax call in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160123/no-transport-error-w-jquery-ajax-call-in-ie)

When setting $.support.cors = true; the load error became "Access is denied", which got me to this on stackoverflow:

[IE9 jQuery AJAX with CORS returns "Access is denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied)

The accepted answer there recommends using a plugin:

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/blob/8754607e5f9ab73ccc37246f0c12fed14f85bd28/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js

Add this plugin to the code and it works..

Comment: That's work (Thanke you), but if i scroll to the next group of thumbnails i get yet this error, i have tried to fix it with a if, but without success...

Comment: You mean the same error again on the same line? Or could it be something different?

Comment: This is same error, but only if click on the arrow to show next 5 thumbs... and on the ie9 is still unvisible, a see only loading.

Comment: I don't have an environment to test the code, if you could provide me with HTML and Source (jpg/js/css) files (no php), I can look in to it for you..

Comment: should i send you files or post the download url here?

Comment: My problem is more that i can't see result on the IE 9, i see only loading image...

Comment: You can drop them in my mail (mail is on my profile page) or put a link here.. But cannot really test IE9 here, cause I'm on a mac..

Comment: Can i send you link for download via your website because i can't :( found email...

Comment: You can mail me at: tim@baascommandeur.nl

Comment: Answer:
It was a "No Transport" error, which got me to this item on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160123/no-transport-error-w-jquery-ajax-call-in-ie

When setting $.support.cors = true; the load error became "Access is denied", which got me to this on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied

The accepted answer there recommends using a plugin:
https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/blob/8754607e5f9ab73ccc37246f0c12fed14f85bd28/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js

Comment: I've added it to the answer..