# XMLHttpRequest Access Denied with AngularJS on any IE version below 10

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, cors

While viewing my application on any Microsoft IE browser of version earlier than 10, I get the following weird error at the console:

[image: console screen shot from the developer console, the view doesn't get resolved due to this error]

I've tried canceling the console with adding the following JavaScript code prior to the AngularJS lib:

```
console.log = function(){};
window.console = {log: function(){}};
```

It didn't make a difference.
The same error in IE 10 appears as:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

probably me trying to get the '/me' from the API in order to check if the user is authenticated or a guest.

Basically. eliminating those annoying console errors each time the server gives a response other than 2XX or 3XX would be great!

UPDATE: This seems to be related to accessing an API over a different sub domain(CORS);

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be setting a mime type or content type for an AJAX request?

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/xdissent/iectrl/issues/2
Are you making any ajax calls? cross-domain ones? seems like a security issue!

Comment: Yes, I am using lots of ajax since I am working in front of a REST api.

Yes, the API is located on another subdomain, so i am using cors.
Should be a problem with AngularJS CORS implementation and IE lt 10?

Comment: http://www.calebwoods.com/2014/05/10/angularjs-ie9-cors-nginx/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The solution that I've been able to achieve via the guidance of an experienced ng-dev at the Google AngularJS group is this [xDomain library](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain).

The setup is very simple, simply place a proxy.html file at the root of your API, with a regex/string for an allowed origin('master'), and a reference to the script at the frontend, and then point to this file from your frontend script('master').

It works by opening the proxy.html file in an iframe, and communicating with the CORS resource using `postMessage`.

Works like a charm with both $http and $resource.

You can also maintain normal functioning for normal browsers by placing the script above all JavaScript library includes:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="xdomain.js" slave="http://example.org/proxy.html"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and took me just 5 minutes to implement!

Comment: Unfortunately (at the time of this post) xDomain does not work with FormData / File uploads of any kind. Issue: https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain/issues/36

Comment: Well, to support XHR-like file upload on legacy browsers, you should use an iFrame fallback my friend (no other way).
Yes - another one beside xDomain

Comment: I'm actually using a Flash fallback. Apparently xdomain just doesn't have support for the FormData API.

Comment: Well, flash is an option, but someone who uses ie7\8 might not have flash as well.
For instance the blueimp jQuery ajax uploader uses an iFrame fallback, and it works well for many users

Comment: Xdomain now provides "Seamless integration with FormData", according to https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

Comment: If I could upvote this answer 50 times I would. Thank you ever so much, @OlegTikhonov, your answer helped me resolve a priority-1 issue early in the morning while working overseas.

Comment: Hey all, thought I should clarify, XDomain does support sending FormData objects cross-domain. However, your browser must support FormData first – so this rules out IE8 and 9. http://caniuse.com/#formdata

Comment: Seems not work for me. I need angular router to run on file:// based. No network and local web server.

Comment: @JennieJi This is not a recommended setup

Comment: Oddly enough...this worked after adding the master/slave.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

Of course your problem is CORS related. IE10 uses a real XmlHttpRequest, but before that, IE did not. By far, the easiest way I have found to resolve these types of issues is to use apache or nginx to proxy the API.
For example, with nginx, in your server `{}` block:

```
location /api {
   proxy_pass http://my.server.name:12345/v1;
   proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Note that even jQuery does not support XDomainRequest and CORS outright, you have to add a plugin to get XDR. Also note, XDR has some severe limitations around CORS.

Comment: We do use proxy_pass in nginx to pass the API requests to gunicorn, and it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Is there any other configuration needed?

Comment: Oh, now I get it...
a proxy_pass for it to be on the same domain.
Need to think whether there are any complications that this could cause.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the `Response Headers` contained

`Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8`

and this is an issue for IE9, since it cannot properly handle/parse JSON Objects in responses.

Switching `Response Headers` to

`Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

In addition, make sure to have the following module included for IE9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28905072/1202371

allowed to receive the response in text and then convert it to JSON object.