# Angular cross-domain request works on Chrome, fails on Firefox and IE

Tags: angularjs, django, django-cors-headers

My Angular app's cross-domain requests through Apache work on Google Chrome, but fail on Firefox with an `Error: a security problem occurred` error.

Here's the `Apache` configuration for my `Django` app:

```
    <Location />  
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://stage.myangularsite.com
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
            Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, authentication, accept, client-security-token"
            Header always set Access-Control-Request-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authentication, client-security-token"

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Authentication Required"
            AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswd" 
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

FYI, On the receiving app, I am using `django-cors-headers` and `django-rest-framework`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your are looking for is the [xDomain Library](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain).

You can find some info on it at this question:

- [XMLHttpRequest Access Denied with AngularJS on any IE version below 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706208/xmlhttprequest-access-denied-with-angularjs-on-any-ie-version-below-10)