# Angular not working on IE 9 & 10 Permisison denied SCRIPT170 and Network Error Access denied

Tags: angular, cross-browser, compatibility

I have integrated and uncommented supporting js in polyfill.ts for IE support for 9,10 and 11. My application works fine on IE 11 but not supporting IE 9 and 10. I am getting white screen with SCRIPT70 Error Permission denied and SCRIPT7002: XmlHttpRequest Network Error, Access denied. Does any one has idea about how to achieve angular support for IE 9,10 and 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest Access Denied with AngularJS on any IE version below 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706208/xmlhttprequest-access-denied-with-angularjs-on-any-ie-version-below-10)

Comment: I am not exactly getting it what it is trying to say. I'm having nginx server where proxy is already implemented