# Ajax call for json fails in ie

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer, jquery

My jquery ajax call for a json file fails in Internet Explorer.
All other explorers are doing good.

Code :

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: myurl + "?randomid="+Math.random(),
                    datatype: "json",
                    mimeType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function(data,status,response) {
                        var JSONdata = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function(e1,e2,e3) {
                        alert(e1 + " " + e2 + " " + e3);
                    }
            });
```

Internet Explorer throws the alert in the error section :

> [Object Object] error No Transport

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of ['No Transport' Error w/ jQuery ajax call in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160123/no-transport-error-w-jquery-ajax-call-in-ie)

Comment: Sorry, Just now saw that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cross domain request.
You need to set this (before ajax call):

```
$.support.cors = true;
```