# $.ajax not working in IE9 version

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I am trying to call a webservice with jQuery ajax. The code is like;

```js
 $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: <Data in JSON format>,
                url: <Url>,        // in same domain
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnFailure
            });
```

However when I run it in IE10 it is working. In IE9 it gives error. I have other pages as well on which I am using jQuery ajax, there it is working fine.

I am clueless now why this is happening.

Comment: what error coming in IE9?

Comment: it straight away going into the OnFailure function. Nothing is logged in Network section of IE9

Comment: ajax error handling function shows, what error code,description?

Comment: Probably can't do `crossDomain; true` and `aysnc: false`.

Comment: I checked the result in Failure method. It says 'No Transport' error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lands on the `crossDomain: true` property, not in the ajax call itself.

This plugin should help: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it turns out that for some reason `jQuery/IE` does not correctly ***urlencode*** `double quotes`.

Check the The *URL* of the request with `IE10` and `IE9`.

Also,
change the `content-type` from `application/json; charset=utf8` to just plain `application/json`

and also try using the `cache: false` parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    .....
    .....
    url: "yoururl",
    cache: false
    .....
});
```

Comment: url is in same format in both modes. I used alert to check the url

Comment: Then, try with other two methods that I had mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I checked the result in Failure method. It says 'No Transport' error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding

```js
$.support.cors = true;
```

at the beginning.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160123/no-transport-error-w-jquery-ajax-call-in-ie) helped me to solve this.