# $.getJSON not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, getjson

I am using following code to grab data from JSON.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.getJSON("http://www.example.com/data.php?id=113&out=json", function(data) {

        $.each(data.issue.page, function(i,item) {
            imagesJSON[i] = item["@attributes"];
        });

       alert(imagesJSON.length);
    });
 });
```

It works in Mozilla, Chrome and other browser but not in IE. (Not in any Version).

Comment: if we could see the JSON result...

Comment: what jquery version and is this link on the domain your script is on?

Comment: Results of adding debug code inside the callback?

Comment: it will display nothing. not even any error.

Comment: Try it with `$.ajax` and `cache: false`

Comment: Could be a same origin policy issue, but then it ought to not work in the other browsers if that was the case. Using $.ajax will allow you to set an `error: function(x) { }` block and then catch the error and look at `x.responseText` to see if an error is returned.

Comment: IE gives me error like **Error, No transport**

Comment: @ketan: what is the actual url and could you provide us the json data?

Comment: @ketan: It appears that bluetoad doesn't allow IE to access their data.php url (you get the same problem when you go to that link directly in IE). So it seems like they have a configuration issue, Nothing to do here other than to contact them about the issue.

Comment: ok thanks for reply and help me a lot. u have good knowledge.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) has a tendency to [cache results in IE](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829225346/http://i.justrealized.com/2008/jquerys-getjson-failing-randomly-in-internet-explorer). Use [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead.

The related call should be something like this in your case:

```
// Not really sure if you've forgot to var 
var imagesJSON = [];

$.ajax({
  url: "www.example.com/data.php?id=113&out=json",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.issue.page, function(i,item) {
        imagesJSON[i] = item["@attributes"];
    });

    alert(imagesJSON.length);
  },
  error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
});
```

Make sure you have `cache: false`.

---

**UPDATE:**

It appears to be a configuration issue at the host with the request url that the OP actually uses. Going to the url directly with IE web browser results in an abort from the host. You can't do much than to report the issue to the host, like an email to the webmaster of the host.

Comment: I use this. Is there any problem  `$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.xyz.com/data.php?id=113&out=json",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
   $.each(data.issue.page, function (i, item) {
            imagesJSON[i] = item["@attributes"];
   alert(imagesJSON.length);
        });
  error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(status + ", " + error);
  
    }`

Comment: @ketan: are you sure you're typing it in right? the value for the key error (which is that function you have there) should be inside the parameter array for the `$.ajax` function.

Comment: The above things give me error in IE like **Error, No transport**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on a page, and I added these lines :

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.0/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and it finaly works for me ;) no more error for IE9

This post helps me [jQuery Call to WebService returns "No Transport" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error/21237086#21237086)