# jQuery.when.done() seems to not work in IE9. No console error either

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have written a jquery addon, with a little help from the internet, which retrieves data from Facebook and does as intended on all browsers tested so far apart from IE9.

I work for local government and unfortunately we still use `IE9` in our builds (It was still `IE8` a few weeks back!! So could have been a lot worse I expect :).

Anyways, I digress, I have added the section of code below which never completes in `IE9`, but does in `IE10`, and other browsers...

Can anyone explain/help me adapt or fix this snippet so that I can get it working in IE9?? And not break it in any other browsers in the process :)??

```
$.when($.getJSON(ogUSER), $.getJSON(ogPOSTS)).done(function (user, posts) {

        // user[0] contains information about the user (name and picture);
        // posts[0].data is an array with wall posts;

        var fb = {
            user: user[0],
            posts: []
        };

        var idxLimit = 0;
        $.each(posts[0].data, function () {

            // We only show links and statuses from the posts feed:
            if (this.type != 'link' && this.type != 'status') {
                return true;
            }

            // Copying the user avatar to each post, so it is
            // easier to generate the templates:
            this.from.picture = fb.user.picture.data.url;

            // Converting the created_time (a UNIX timestamp) to
            // a relative time offset (e.g. 5 minutes ago):
            this.created_time = relativeTime(this.created_time * 1000);

            // Converting URL strings to actual hyperlinks:
            this.message = urlHyperlinks(this.message);

            //remove all anchors
            //var content = $('<div>' + this.message + '</div>');
            //content.find('a').remove();
            //this.message = content.html();

            fb.posts.push(this);
            idxLimit++;
            if (idxLimit === 2) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

In all browsers, not including IE9, if I insert a breakpoints anywhere within the `.done()` callback it stops execution and I can debug. With IE9 the breakpoint is not reached leading me to believe there is an issue with IE9 script engine and `jQuery.when()` API call, or the `.done()` callback method...

But, I'm just guessing at the mo... I've been searching the web for the last few hours to see if anyone else has happened upon a similar issue but to no avail. I hope some of the more experienced coders here can help... would be very much appreciated. Until then the search goes on :)

Thanks for your time folks ;)

PS. I don't receive any console errors what so ever in IE9 running the script...

TartanBono

Comment: add a `fail` handler and see if it is triggered.

Comment: Just wondering, why using IE9 and not IE10/11?

Comment: @A.Wolff Do you not know how Government agencies work? lol ;)

Comment: @epascarello yes but from IE9 to IE10, oh wait, i see it now... :)

Comment: @epascarello do you mean to the `when()` or each of the `getJSON()` calls? I tried but got 'Uncaught TypeError' for attempting to add to the `when()`. Looking at the jquery api and cannot see `fail` handler? but I do for the `getJSON()` methods...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the link, I managed to add the handlers to the `getJSON()` methods before I just read your reply and in IE9 I get an error returned to the console... **No Transport** for each of the calls? Will this be same error returned following the`ajaxError` handler method? or should I register the handler as described in the link?

Comment: Are you making a cross domain call? or http to https?

Comment: @epascarello yes, its a call to facebook open graph. I found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315211/getjson-not-workin-in-ie) while looking around for a possible solution but it doesnt seem to have made any difference to my results :(

The `ogPOSTS` variable is `https://graph.facebook.com/Facebook.ID/posts/?access_token=123456789101112|aAbB0OLslQ0X52k08my7JwqEzazZ&date_format=U&limit=5&callback=` (with proper FacebookID & access_token used), trying the correct URL in the IE9 browser returns the data expected...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied

Comment: @epascarello, thanks for that, been to use some of the techniques described in post but no joy so far... I think my situation seems to be calling https protocol from a page on http. I tried another endpoint on http and it returns ok... Thanks for your help so far... cheers