# getJSON doesn't append data in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, append, getjson

I'm using $.getJSON to append Google Sheets data to my HTML document. The data flows in on all browsers except Internet Explorer and I'm not sure why. I've read other threads on the issue but can't figure out a solution – my problem seems to be a little different because of the appending. Any help would be appreciated!

Specifics: I'm using jQuery v2.1.3 and when I try to load the page in Internet Explorer through Browserling, this is the error message that pops up –

**Exception in window.onload: Error: An error has occurredJSPlugin.3005**

Here's the specific script I'm using:

```
var profile = $('#profile');
    $().ready(getSchool);

    function getSchool() {
        $.getJSON('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1t_k4uQt04StZqiGqcoBAti5xauCtOr0_pT4FCtV8mTQ/1/public/values?alt=json')
            .done(function(data) {
                var arr = Array.from(data.feed.entry);
                profile.html('');
                arr.forEach(function(e) {
                    var info = `HTML GOES HERE`
                    profile.append(info);
                })
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('Error retrieving school data');
            })
    }
```

Comment: `$.getJSON has a tendency to cache results in IE. Use $.ajax instead.`

Comment: are there any errors that you can see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.getJSON not workin in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315211/getjson-not-workin-in-ie)

Comment: @JohnKane I added the error into the post. But I have to use an emulated Internet Explorer through Browserling so I'm not sure how informative that is.

Comment: @Alex I haven't used ajax before (or getJSON for that matter) but I'll try to switch it over to that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @NickD It's literally the same thing, just a different wrapper. Here's a good reference for you: [`How To Use JQuery’s $.Ajax() Function`](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

Comment: @Alex Thanks! I'll check that out and try to switch it over – appreciate it.