# using jquery ajax to get data from password protected classic ASP page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to use ajax to request a password protected page, pass credentials, and then get the html from the resulting page? 
I've been playing around with my asp.net mvc application and so far i haven't been able to get it working. here's what my view looks like:

```
 @Code
  ViewData("Title") = "Index"
 End Code


 <h2>eWeb Job Count</h2>
 <div id="mydiv">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://102.143.240.117/dataviews.asp",
    data: "'Administrator', 'password'",
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (dataviewhtml) {
        $('#mydiv').html(dataviewhtml);

    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
        $('#mydiv').html(errorMessage);
    }

});
});
</script>
```

when i load the page, i don't get any error messages... just a blank page. 
is it possible to pass data to a pop up window via ajax?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. [**jQuery.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) supports `username` and `password` options, you could pass,when requesting:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://102.143.240.117/dataviews.asp",
    username : 'Administrator',
    password : 'password',
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (dataviewhtml) {
        $('#mydiv').html(dataviewhtml); 
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
        $('#mydiv').html(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi.  i added those two items but still nothing.  No errors either.  I tried using the debug tools in IE 9 ... put a break point on the document.ready().  but i'm not getting anything back.  I added "console.log(dataiewhtml);" right after i do " $('#mydiv').html(dataviewhtml); " in the successful branch of the ajax call.  but it's not displaying anything either.

Comment: i just tried adding some alert statements in the javascript. and it looks like it's going to the error handler of the ajax call. the error message it's showing is [object Object].  any ideas what that is?

Comment: @dot Have you configured your server correctly for permissions?

Comment: @dot Are you sure , you want to use HTTP Authentication, that I was thinking of -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: i changed my error handler to look like:  error: function (a, errorMessage, c).  And then i include all three variables / parms in my alert statement.  The message box is displaying "[object Object]" for the first parameter (XMLHttpRequest I believe),"error" for the message, and "No Transport" for the last parameter - errorThrown.  I'm currently reviewing this post to see if it's relevant to my situation:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error

Comment: can you give me something specific to check with regards to your security comment? thank you, by the way.

Comment: @dot Little question. Are you trying to use `Basic_access_authentication`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12823/discussion-between-dot-and-engineer)