# Calling REST Api with JSONP & JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

I have created REST API in MVC4, it is working fine when I compose request from fiddler. But in my application, I need to call through jsonp because it would cross domain request. But when I'm calling this service it gives me error as shown below:

Jquery JsonP Call ..

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:81/api/sites/GetDomainAvailability?apikey=asfasfdsf&callback=?",
        data: { SubDomain: subDomain, ParentDomain: parentDomain, ResellerId: resellerId },
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            if (callback)
                callback(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            if (callback)
                error(response.d);
        },
    });
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are not doing JSONP. It's still POST request. To make it JSONP you need simply to add `dataType: "jsonp"` to you `$.ajax()` call. You can also remove some other redundancy parameters like content-type and 'callback' param (but that's optional). So, your code should looke like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:81/api/sites/GetDomainAvailability?apikey=asfasfdsf",
    data: { SubDomain: subDomain, ParentDomain: parentDomain, ResellerId: resellerId },
    datatype: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) { /* ... */ },
    error: function (response) { /* ... */ },
});
```

Be also ready, that your request will be transformed to a GET one and will look like
`/GetDomainAvailability?apikey=key&callback=jquery123&SubDomain=sss&ParentDomain=ppp&ResellerId=123&_=4398572349857`

So, prepare your server-side code for that.