# File Read ajax call browser compatibility

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cross-browser

I am trying to run below given code.It is working properly in **IE browser** but in other browser it is not working.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4 /jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(){

    alert("1");     
        $.ajax({url:"file://///30.170.12.75/Shared/a.html"
        ,success:function(result) {$("#div1").html(result);}
        ,error: function(result) {alert("2");}
         });
  });
});
<script>
```

As i know jquery api provide us browser compatibility also but it is not working any of other browser.

Please Let me know the reason so that in future i will be taking care of them.

Comment: Are you getting alert('2') for error?. If so, can you pass that result to alert and tell us what error?

Comment: @Moniecorleone I am getting Object when i am putting result in alert instead of 2.

Comment: @Boaz Thanks for your reply ajax call is not working.It is always displaying me alert("2") for other borwsers.

Comment: What is the expected datatype? try specifying datatype: "text",

Comment: @Moniecorleone Thankx for your reply but i did not get you.Could you please explain it.

Comment: The error you are getting is 'no transport' Error. there are similar threads with this issue. please refer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error

Comment: For identifying the type of error you getting, alert 'result.statusText'

Answer (score 2):

You're using `file://` protocol and most browsers don't allow access to this if the source document is not server with the `file://` protocol.

For ajax requests, most browsers will block the requests if the destination protocol is a `file://` protocol. However, IE doesn't seems to behave like this and still allow the request to finish.

If you're using Chrome, you can change this by starting Chrome with a `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

(Is it really to be `file://` and not `http://` or other things?)

Comment: I am directly accessing this "file://///30.170.12.75/Shared/a.html" url in FF and chrome working properly.

Comment: Directly accessing a URL does not invoke the security limits enforced on JavaScript based attempts to access URLs. Most browsers won't allow access to different files even if the source document is served using `file:`. Use HTTP.

Comment: @Java_Alert — IE isn't "most browsers". Different browsers implement different levels of protection for local files. IE allowing it explains why I keep getting phishing/trojan emails with HTML attachments they want me to open though.

Comment: @Quentin Http is not working at all. I have already checked it.

Comment: From a file URI, most browsers will block access to other file URIs and HTTP URIs. Load the original document over HTTP and use Ajax to request resources from the same origin as the original document.