# jQuery Web Service Call, I.E 9,8

Tags: jquery, web-services, sharepoint-2013

The below function is used to get information from web service using jQuery. This code works fine in I.E 10 but it returns error "No Transport" in I.E 8 and I.E 9.

function GetDemo(User){

```
var webMethod = "http://---------/Service.asmx/Demo";
var parameters = '{"UserName":"'+ User + '"}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {

    if(typeof msg.d[0] !== "undefined") {
    $("#Designation").html(msg.d[0]['Designation']);
    }
    else
    {
    // $("[title='Name']").val("");     
    }           
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       alert(xhr.status);
       alert(xhr.responseText);
       alert(thrownError);
   }    });
```

}

Any suggestions ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error

Comment: @Delphian

jQuery.support.cors = true; 

Found the answer , you just need to put the above line of code before ajax calling for I.E 7, & I.E 8.

Comment: hope it resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.support.cors = true;

just add these lines before calling the service.