# IE8/9 'No Transport' Error jQuery, $.support.cors = true; not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I got 'No Transport' Error (firebug lite say that), on IE console just write LOG: [object Object]

After i add jQuery.support.cors = true; just before jQuery.ajax still the same, but my ie is hmmm "broken" so now i cant load firebug lite to see what he say now...

Any other fix? How to start firebug lite or other ways to debug JS?

EDIT: gallery load after i open IE 9 console

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that CORS isn't supported fully in IE until version 10 is released. Check this out: http://caniuse.com/cors

more Info: [jQuery Call to WebService returns "No Transport" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)

Comment: amm but gallery load after i open IE 9 console :S