# Using $.ajax POST to interface with particle.io

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post

I'm trying to call a function in Particle.io using ajax POST. It works when I plug in the URL and parameters into Postman.

[image]

Now when I'm trying to do the same in NodeJS, I get the error: No Transport. I've installed jQuery v2.1.4 and jsdom v3.1.2.
What am I doing wrong in translating what I have on Postman into ajax?

```
        $.ajax({
      url: requestURL,
      method: 'POST',
headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer <accesstoken',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
          'arg': 'on'
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      //contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(){
        console.log('success!');
      },
      error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
```

Particle.io API reference: https://docs.particle.io/reference/api/

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Here are the screenshots:[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lK3Cm.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fbPke.png

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error