# jQuery ajax call not working on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function GetSelectedTextValue() { 
    var selMenu = document.getElementById("selMenu"); 
    var selMenuValue = selMenu.value; 
    var selOptions=document.getElementById("selOptions"); 
    var selOptionsValue = selOptions.value; 
    var UserInput=$("#txtClaimNumber").val(); 
    if(selMenuValue=="Claims_Related" && selOptionsValue=="1") { 
        Claim_related_api(UserInput); 
    } 
}

function Claim_related_api( Claim_number) {
    var model = { PolicyNumber: "236426891", ClaimNumber: Claim_number };

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),                
        url: 'http://asplb-dev-00433/api/ClaimDetailsByClaim',
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json"

    }).done(function (res) {               
        alert(res[0].CLAIM_ID);

    });
}
```

Comment: how you are calling function `Claim_related_api` ? share that code too. Also did you get any error in your browser console? share that too

Comment: function GetSelectedTextValue() {
        var selMenu = document.getElementById("selMenu");
        var selMenuValue = selMenu.value;
var selOptions=document.getElementById("selOptions");
    var selOptionsValue = selOptions.value;
var UserInput=$("#txtClaimNumber").val();  
if(selMenuValue=="Claims_Related" && selOptionsValue=="1")
{
Claim_related_api(UserInput);

}
 }

Comment: from this method i am calling the Claim_related_api  function

Comment: [Please read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: no am not getting any errors, its just that when the debugger reach the ajax code it reaches to the end and it shows res as undefined.

Comment: add success and error callback functions and attach debugger in them and check whether it is success or fail.

Comment: will you attach that as i am new to jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
function Claim_related_api( Claim_number) {
    var model = { PolicyNumber: "236426891", ClaimNumber: Claim_number };



    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),                
        url: 'http://asplb-dev-00433/api/ClaimDetailsByClaim',
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });

}
```

Comment: @aditya tyagi : Add `debugger;` in both success and error and check in console which function is hit.

Comment: debugger is going in error function and giving error is undefined.

Comment: change the line `error: function ()` to `error: function (error)` and check it

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error