# JavaScript & SO policy: Interface with service without introducing dependency on e.g ASP.net

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, json, angularjs

So I have a program serving up JSON via HTTP running at localhost:8080 and I am hoping to hook a front end up to it (AngularJS).

I'm interested to know if there is anyway to interface with such a service without introducing a dependency on something like ASP.NET or PHP so on in order to serve as a proxy between the service and the browser.

I understand the same origin policy, cross site scripting threat yada yada yada.
Grateful for all constructive contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using jsonp instead of json to avoid the aforementioned cross site scripting...

here is another answer along the same lines

[Ajax Cross Domain Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648048/ajax-cross-domain-calls)

Comment: Thanks I will have a read. I'm really after the solution that will allow maximum portability, so minimal configuration and setup overhead.

Comment: JSONP is going to be the way I think. Thanks.