# How to get data by json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, azure

i have json file which is hosted on the server. this is the link.

http://jsonji.azurewebsites.net/json1.json,

and i am able to get json data when this file is on the my local system. this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonji.azurewebsites.net/json1.json",
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.person, function () {
            $("ul").append("<li> Name:" + this['name'] + "</li><li>Age" + this['age'] + "</li><br/>");
        });
    });
});
```

if you know then please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax Cross Domain Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648048/ajax-cross-domain-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not able to read this JSON file is because you're browser is trying to make a cross-domain request and most likely CORS Setting is not enabled on your website.

See this thread for more details: [HTTP OPTIONS request on Azure Websites fails due to CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981339/http-options-request-on-azure-websites-fails-due-to-cors).